# Spring + Multiple Databases (Dynamic)

Tags: java, database, spring, architecture

We are using Spring in our enterprise application. There can be multiple customers, each customer will have his own database.

> Customer 1  - cust_one_db
>   Customer 2  - cust_two_db
>   ..

These customers are enrolled by an external application. So the external application creates database for every new customer.
Now when a user wants to log in to our enterprise application he has to provide his customer id, depending upon which our enterprise application would connect to respected database.

What is the correct way to achieve this using Spring? suggestions for external libraries would also be helpful.

Comment: Are you using any ORM technologies? Or you using spring DAO?

Comment: We are not using any ORM as there is another server component which also updates the database.

Comment: It seems no one has faced this before!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to adopt a similar concept to what is often done when per user connection pooling is required.

Hope this helps

Regards
Ian Lim